# FileStream and creating folders

Tags: c#, filestream

Just a quick question. I'm using something like this

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
```

I was wondering whether there was a parameter I could pass to it to force it to create the folder if it doesn't exist. At the moment an exception is throw if folder isn't found.

If there is a better method then using `FileStream` I'm open to ideas.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Use [Directory.CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx):

> **Directory.CreateDirectory Method (String)**
>
> Creates all directories and subdirectories as specified by path.

Example:

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\SomeUser\My Documents\Foo\Bar\Baz\text1.txt";

Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName));

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    // ...
}
```

([Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) returns the directory part of the file name.)

Comment: Say i have /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/file.txt as the filename and folder1 doesn't exist. Will the above create all 4 folders.

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko: I just tested it and, yes, it does.

Comment: What would happen if the folder already existed and you ran that line

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko: Directory.CreateDirectory does not throw an exception if the directory already exists. It does nothing in this case.

Comment: One edge case where this will throw an exception is if the input filename does not contain a path (e.g. "text1.txt").  In this case, Path.GetDirectoryName will return an empty string, and Directory.CreateDirectory with throw an ArgumentException.

Comment: I tested this in Linux with .NET 6 and it created a folder with the name of the file. Testing in Windows it doesn't create a folder named text1.txt.

Answer (score 20):

Something like:

```
void EnsureFolder(string path)
{
    string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    // If path is a file name only, directory name will be an empty string
    if (directoryName.Length > 0)
    {
        // Create all directories on the path that don't already exist
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this so less upvoted, its a good way to check and create folder.

Comment: @ChaitanyaGadkari likely because Directory.CreateDirectory does not throw an exception if the directory already exists; so dtb's answer is succinct for most people facing a similar problem.